# Remote: true on simple form not making AJAX request but rendering blank page instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, vite, ruby-on-rails-7, remote-forms

I know there are many posts about this issue, but most of them are really old and none includes ActionCable. So here comes the challenge:

I am building a chat functionality with ActionCable and the messages are broadcasting successfully. The message is also rendered instantly for the receiver, but on the senders end a blank page is rendered as usual for a post request (message create form). I am receiving a `status code of 200`, which I am triggering in my message create method, but I obviously want to stay on the same page and insert the HTML through JS (using Stimulus for JS).

app/views/chats/show.html.erb - form to create message

```
 <%= simple_form_for [@chat, @message], remote: true,
    html: {
      class: 'chat__form',
      data: {
        action: "turbo:submit-end->chat-subscription#resetForm"
      }
    } do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :content,
                  label: false,
                  placeholder: "Message ##{@name}",
                  input_html: { class: 'chat__form-input' } %>
      <%= button_tag(class: 'chat__form-button') do %>
        <%= image_tag('icons/send.svg') %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb - create method

```
def create
    @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.chat = @chat
    @message.user = current_user
    if @message.save
      ChatChannel.broadcast_to(
        @chat,
        render_to_string(partial: "messages/message", locals: {message: @message})
      )
      head :ok
    end
  end
```

app/javascript/controllers/chat_subscription_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { chatId: Number }
  static targets = ['messages', 'form']

  connect() {
    this.channel = createConsumer().subscriptions.create(
      { channel: 'ChatChannel', id: this.chatIdValue },
      { received: data => this.#insertMessageAndScrollDown(data) }
    )
    console.log(`Subscribed to the chat with the id ${this.chatIdValue}.`)
    console.log(this.messagesTarget)
  }

  #insertMessageAndScrollDown(data) {
    this.messagesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data)
    this.messagesTarget.scrollTo(0, this.messagesTarget.scrollHeight)
  }

  resetForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.target.reset()
  }

  disconnect() {
    console.log('Unsubscribed from the chat')
    this.channel.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

As I said - it all works perfectly on the receivers end. Therefore I can be sure that the channel is set up correctly and that my JS methods work, too. I think that the remote: true is not triggering and that the form is being submitted locally. I just don't know what my setup is missing. I believe that because I am using Vite instead of Webpacker, something is not set up correctly. But I can't find any ressources on this, either.

What about redis, how does it come into play here?

Comment: Forget about `remote: true`.  You do not need or want Rails UJS or jQuery UJS in a Rails 7 application. Both are obsolete (jQuery was dumped way back in 2016) and Turbo  provides the functionality that was previously (badly) provided by Rails UJS.

Comment: Whats your suggestion to achieve what I am trying to achieve then?

Comment: I would find some basic tutorials on how to CRUD with Turbo and its concepts and then when you have a grasp of that figure out how to integrate it with ActionCable. I think if you're trying to learn both at the same time your mind is just going to explode. Also forget the terms "local" and "remote" - that naming is the worst part of Rails UJS and it's not a good way to reason about syncronous vs asyncronous requests.

Comment: Can you give me feedback to my usage of Vite? Every time I render a page (let's say from the index page to a show), I am expecting a fetch request to happen if Turbo is added to the project correctly. Is that right? Because it is not happening. It is making HTML requests.

Comment: Sorry, I have never even heard of it. If you're just doing this for learning purposes I would just stick with the default Rails toolchain. There is enough to wrap your head around anyways.

Comment: vite, turbopack - every week a new revolutionary tool. do you have `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";`  in *app/javascript/entrypoints/application.js*

Comment: yes, i do. i migrated to webpack last night, unfortunately. but now my chat works perfectly. for some reason i couldnt get turbo to work. thanks for your support, though.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a quick try, this is a working setup:

```bash
rails new hello_vite --skip-javascript
cd hello_vite

bundle add turbo-rails stimulus-rails
mkdir app/javascript
bin/rails turbo:install:node
bin/rails stimulus:install:node

bundle add vite_rails
bundle exec vite install

bin/rails g scaffold Chat
bin/rails g scaffold Message content:text
bin/rails g channel Chat
bin/rails g stimulus chat_subscription
bin/rails db:migrate
bin/rails runner Chat.create
```

```
bin/vite dev
```

```
bin/rails s
```

That's about it. Maybe you were missing `turbo-rails` gem, so server didn't recognize *TURBO_STREAM* format, check in rails console:

```rb
>> Mime[:turbo_stream]
=> #<Mime::Type:0x00007f15104567e0 @hash=-2016241814324581175, @string="text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", @symbol=:turbo_stream, @synonyms=[]>
```

---

```rb
# app/javascript/entrypoints/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "../controllers"

# app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
def create
  @chat = Chat.first
  @message = Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.save
    ChatChannel.broadcast_to(@chat, render_to_string(@message))
    head :ok
  end
end

# app/channels/chat_channel.rb
def subscribed
  stream_for Chat.find(params[:id])
end

# app/views/messages/index.html.erb
<%= tag.div data: {
  controller: "chat-subscription",
  chat_subscription_chat_id_value: Chat.first.id
} do %>
  <%= render "form", message: Message.new %>
  <%= tag.div id: :messages, data: {chat_subscription_target: :messages} do %>
    <%= render @messages %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# app/views/messages/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with model: message,
  data: { action: "turbo:submit-end->chat-subscription#resetForm" },
  html: { style: "position:sticky;top:0;background-color:white;" } do |form| %>
  #       ^^^^^^^^ this is just to test the auto scroll ^^^^^^^^
  <%= form.text_area :content, placeholder: "message..." %> <br>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/javascript/controllers/chat_subscription_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable";
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { chatId: Number };
  static targets = ["messages"];
  connect() {
    this.channel = createConsumer().subscriptions.create(
      { channel: "ChatChannel", id: this.chatIdValue },
      { received: (data) => this.insertMessageAndScrollDown(data) }
    );
  }
  insertMessageAndScrollDown(data) {
    this.messagesTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", data);
    this.messagesTarget.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
  }
  resetForm(event) {
    event.target.reset();
  }
  disconnect() {
    this.channel.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: hey alex! thanks so much, i appreciate the effort. i did have the turbo-rails gem installed though, also imported. currently, i dont have the time to migrate back to vite to check it out. i will test it in the near future and accept your answer if i can get it to a working state. thanks!